# What to do when the OP asks for a solution in one language and then moves to another?

Tags: discussion

What do I do if an OP asks for a solution in one language and later you discover that they have asked another question requiring a solution in a different language, in effect orphaning the original question?

Given that they have now not only lost interest in the original question, but have also effectively orphaned it, as they are not going to accept any answer provided, the issue becomes that we have a valid question and one or more valid answers but they may not get the attention they deserve in the future.

Should the question and or answer/s be deleted or should they just be left sitting there?

Comment: why wouldn't it get as much visibility as other questions because the OP isn't looking into it? If he never accepts any answer, just move on. Good solutions will be upvoted by other users

Comment: A question with no accepted answer, might well be overlooked - just a thought.

Comment: why? Accepting is JUST the OP's prerogative, no one else's. If I land on a question for which I have a similar problem, a checkmark or no will NOT make anything change in my behavior towards the answers...

Comment: @RolfofSaxony You're going to have to support that assertion, as I would find that *highly* unlikely.

Comment: The body and title of your question appear to have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Servy the title states the issue, the body states the dilemma

Comment: @RolfofSaxony The title is implying that the question is edited from asking about one language to asking about another.  The body asks about the author losing interest in a question.

Comment: @Servy Because in this particular case, they moved on, and asked another question, requiring a solution in a different language.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony And that's not at all stated in your question, instead implying that they edited the question instead, which is a *very* different situation.

Comment: @Servy In that case I apologise if my question was unclear and therefore misleading.

Comment: Clarified the question. Hopefully, that now states the problem properly, although to be fair, I have already accepted the answer given and accept the consensus, just leave it be.

Comment: Another small point of detail here (just thinking out loud) : unless the question in the new language is another way to do the same thing, it could be the OP is just proficient in multiple languages, no? Now if he asked "how do I do X in php" then "how do I do X in go" with the same X.... that's something else :p

Comment: Even then, @Patrice, someone could just be investigating the writing of a program in one of two different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OP can't be bothered to follow up on their previous questions, then clearly they don't feel that their questions or the answers deserve their attention.

But that's just one person. Think of the hundreds, possibly thousands of people who might come across your answers in the next few months or years. I'm sure at least a handful of them will stop by and express their appreciation for your answers through votes. Not accepting an answer isn't going to stop their questions from showing up in search results and the like.

If the OP doesn't care, it's their loss. And that's assuming they really don't care — there are a number of other reasons an OP may not accept an answer, some of which you can't really blame them for.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just asking! I still haven't got used to the quite aggressive nature of comments in Meta. Seems like you ask a simple question and you get your head bitten off.

Comment: @Rolf of Saxony: Lovely place, ain't it?

Comment: @RolfOfSaxony sorry, I sounded aggressive? If you really got my comments as aggressive, buckle up in Meta, it'll be a tough ride (if you really did, I do apologize, I never meant this as aggressive)

Comment: Give me time, I'll get there.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony in any case, I do apologize if you thought I was being aggressive. I know I have a tendency to be curt and my use of caps to put emphasis doesn't help... but in no way did I mean any of what I said as aggressive ^^

Comment: No problem whatsoever, thank you for your concern.